# Nested if statement. Following same condition every time

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I am only getting the false condition to print to the applet. I am assuming that there is something wrong with my nested if statements?

ClickableBox.Java

```
public class ClickableBox extends MouseAdapter {

  private int x, y, width, height;
  private Color borderColor, backColor, oldColor;
  private boolean drawBorder, clicked, isX;
  private Container parent;
  TheGame game;

  public ClickableBox(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color borderColor,
      Color backColor, boolean drawBorder, TheGame parent) {

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.borderColor = borderColor;
    this.backColor = backColor;
    this.drawBorder = drawBorder;
    this.parent = parent;

  }

  public void draw(Graphics g) {

    oldColor = g.getColor();
    g.setColor(backColor);
    g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    if (drawBorder) {
      g.setColor(borderColor);
      g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
    }
    g.setColor(oldColor);
  }

  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    if (x < e.getX() && e.getX() < x + width && y < e.getY()
        && e.getY() < y + height) {
      clicked = true;
      setX(!isX);
      parent.repaint();

    }
  }

  public boolean isClicked() {
    return clicked;
  }

  public int getX() {
    return x;
  }

  public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
  }

  public int getY() {
    return y;
  }

  public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
  }

  public int getWidth() {
    return width;
  }

  public void setWidth(int width) {
    this.width = width;
  }

  public int getHeight() {
    return height;
  }

  public void setHeight(int height) {
    this.height = height;
  }

  public Color getBorderColor() {
    return borderColor;
  }

  public void setBorderColor(Color borderColor) {
    this.borderColor = borderColor;
  }

  public Color getBackColor() {
    return backColor;
  }

  public void setBackColor(Color backColor) {
    this.backColor = backColor;
  }

  public boolean isDrawBorder() {
    return drawBorder;
  }

  public void setDrawBorder(boolean drawBorder) {
    this.drawBorder = drawBorder;
  }

  public boolean isX() {
    return isX;
  }

  public void setX(boolean isX) {
    this.isX = isX;
  }

}
```

TicTacToeBox.Java

```
 public class TicTacToeBox extends ClickableBox {

  Container parent;
  TheGame game;

  public TicTacToeBox(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color borderColor,
      Color backColor, boolean drawBorder, TheGame parent) {
    super(x, y, width, height, borderColor, backColor, drawBorder, parent);

    this.parent = parent;

  }

  public void draw(Graphics g) {

    if (isClicked()) {
      if (super.isX()) {
        g.drawLine(getX(), getY(), getX() + getWidth(), getY() + getHeight());
        g.drawLine(getX() + getWidth(), getY(), getX(), getY() + getHeight());
        if (isDrawBorder()) {
          g.drawRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
      } else {
        g.drawOval(getX() + 3, getY() + 3, getWidth() - 6, getHeight() - 6);
        if (isDrawBorder()) {
          g.drawRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
      }
    } else {
      g.drawRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
  }

}
```

Here is the actual applet code as well... TheGame.java

```
public class TheGame extends Applet {

  private final int START_X = 20;
  private final int START_Y = 40;
  private final int ROWS = 3;
  private final int COLS = 3;
  private final int BOX_WIDTH = 70;
  private final int BOX_HEIGHT = 70;

  private TicTacToeBox boxes[][];

  private Button resetButton;
  private boolean isX;

  private boolean blank;

  public void init() {
    boxes = new TicTacToeBox[ROWS][COLS];

    resize(300, 300);
    buildBoxes();

    resetButton = new Button("Reset Game");
    resetButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        buildBoxes();
        repaint();
      }
    });
    add(resetButton);
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // loop through the boxes rows

    setX(!isX);
    // System.out.println(isX());

    for (int row = 0; row < boxes.length; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < boxes[row].length; col++) {

        boxes[row][col].draw(g);

        if (boxes[row][col].isClicked()) {

        }
      }
    }

  }

  private void buildBoxes() {

    for (int row = 0; row < boxes.length; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < boxes[row].length; col++) {
        boxes[row][col] = new TicTacToeBox(START_X + col * BOX_WIDTH, START_Y
            + row * BOX_HEIGHT, BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT, Color.black,
            Color.white, true, this);
        addMouseListener(boxes[row][col]);

      }
    }
  }

  public boolean isX() {
    return isX;
  }

  public void setX(boolean isX) {
    this.isX = isX;
  }

  public boolean isBlank() {
    return blank;
  }

  public void setBlank(boolean blank) {
    this.blank = blank;
  }

}
```

Any input as to how I can get the conditions to alternate from true to false and actually output what I have for each condition would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The indentation of your code is inconsistent -- e.g., the line saying `if(isDrawBorder())` is indented by less than its predecessor, even though there's no close-brace there, and several of the close-braces at the end appear to be mismatched with their partners. It will be easier for readers to tell what you intended (and therefore to tell whether your code doesn't match your intentions) if you fix this.

Comment: Don't use if(something == true) {} else if (something == false){}. Just use if(something){}else{}. boolean are either true or false and writing `== true` is redundant and less readable.

Comment: Fixed some obvious stuff in your code, like not comparing a boolean to true or false, and testing first for the positive outcome, then negative. Easier to read. Now, use this code and see if you can find what's wrong. The code is quite simple.

Comment: So with those minor fixes, I still have an issue where when I click each box, even though the condition is true, it prints an oval and not an X.

Comment: If it draws an oval, then `isX` returned `false`. Add a `System.out.println` to convince yourself.

Comment: I did and it is returning True, then false, then true. So that is why I am lost.

Comment: btw.: `TheGame` is a bogus name. Why don't you use `TicTacToe` if it is TicTacToe?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I added information

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Any thoughts?

Comment: Why are you changing `isX` in your `paint` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You reinstantiate constantly TheGame, this is why you get always the same branch of your if. `game` should be a member of you enclosing class not a local variable and you should initalize it in your constructor:

```
public class TicTacToeBox {
    private TheGame game;

    // I am guessing your constructor is something like this (but it is just guessing)
    public TicTacToeBox(int i, int j , int k , int l, Color c1, Color c2, boolean b, TheGame game) {
         ...
         this.game = game;
    }
    ...
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        // TheGame game = new TheGame();
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am still gettin Ovals drawn every time. It is not alternating like it should. The problem may be in TheGame.Java code....

Comment: @MontyTheMack OK, I get it better now, your draw method is inside your TicTacToeBox class. So your TicTacToeBox class should get a reference from TheGame through the constructor and keep that reference

Comment: @MontyTheMack If you have changed anything in your code, then update your question. How do you think we can help you otherwise? Where **are** you storing your `TheGame` instance? We don't see that.

Comment: I have tried that, that would just change every thing that has been clicked to either an x or an o. I would like for me to click a box and an X appear, then click another box and an O appear. While the X stays as an X.

Comment: That is located in my CLickableBox class, I will add.

Comment: @MontyTheMack Show us the full code of your TicTacToeClass and your mouse listeners. We are wasting time trying to guess what you are doing and not understanding your objectives

Comment: @MontyTheMack So in your mouseReleased, you should initialize isX (the one of ClickableBox) to theGame.isX() and then toggle the value of isX of TheGame. (stop instantiating TheGame everywhere!). In your draw method, use the isX of ClickableBox, not the one of TheGame. Finally, in your Constructors of ClickableBox and TicTacToeBox, change the type of parent from Container to TheGame. Instead of using game, use parent now since it is the TheGame reference.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet  `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ClickableBox.mouseReleased(ClickableBox.java:50)`
Getting this error for the following line:
`isX = !game.isX();`

Comment: @MontyTheMack read the last line of my previous comment! Use parent.isX() instead of game.isX() (and same thing to toggle the value on the next line)

Comment: @GuillaumePolet I am getting X, X, X now. I have updated my code above with your suggested changes.

Comment: In your mouseReleased, you forgot to toggle the state of your parent and change `Container parent` to `TheGame parent`! You should have this: `setX(!parent.isX()); parent.setX(!parent.isX());` instead of `setX(!isX);`